# How to use an NPM Mirror

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The npm registry is down again, resulting in `npm install` not working.

**Question:** How do we use `npm` to pull packages from npm mirrors? Are there any recommended npm mirrors?

Answer (score 14):

use the npm mirror

```
npm set registry http://ec2-46-137-149-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

you can reset this later with npm set registry

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then use it normally:

```
npm install express
```

You can also see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/streunerlein/3331671) for more information on the above solution.

Comment: How do we know this registry isn't compromised?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Gist with what seems to be complete instructions for setting up a mirror, with a demo mirror/example.](https://gist.github.com/streunerlein/3331671).  Not sure if that person's mirror is still running, but the example provided seems simple enough:

```
$ npm set registry http://domain.of.your.npm.mirror.com
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question passed almost ten years, I will recommand you to use [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) in 2023, set the mirror registry like this:

```
pnpm set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/
```